# Trigger an asp.net LinkButton with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a page configured to hide a FileUpload control, so when you click a button it shows the file upload windows and after you choose the file it automatically submits it to the server.

Ir order for this to work i created 2 linkbuttons and a file upload but only one of the buttons is visible. When you click the button it triggers the fileupload window and when the FileUpload control has a change it triggers the submit (invisible) button. The proble I'm having is that only the OnClientClick is being triggered and the server side code is not running

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('<%= button.ClientID %>').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('<%= fileupload.ClientID %>').click();
    return false;    
}

document.getElementById('<%= fileupload.ClientID %>').onchange = function () {
     document.getElementById('<%= save.ClientID %>').click();
}
</script>
```

The save button has a onclientclick to show a modal window and should send to server

```
OnClick="lnkChange_OnClick" OnClientClick="ShowModalDialog(0);"
```

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think __doPostBack('','') will help you.
Call _doPostBack function from your client side function. It will postback the page.

Comment: I tried both __doPostBack('<%= save.ClientID %>',''); and __doPostBack('lnkChange_OnClick',''); but none called the server side code

Comment: It will not be raising the server side event. It will got to Page_Load, from there you call your method.

Comment: And how can I analyse it in page_load so I can call the function I need? Thanks

Comment: please look into this link                                             http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/